# Assigning values to javascript array elements doesn’t work when looped (classic .asp), but it works without looping, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp-classic

I am using classic .asp.
I have the following:

```
<script language="javascript">
var JSintTotal = <% =intTotal%>;
var JSarrHotelsProdCols = Create2DArray(JSintTotal);
<%
for x = 0 to intTotal - 1
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][0] =  "&arrHotelsProdCols(0,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][1] = '"&arrHotelsProdCols(1,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][2] = '"&arrHotelsProdCols(2,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][3] = '"&arrHotelsProdCols(3,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
next

%>
</script>
```

The Create2DArray() function is working properly, I grabbed from this site.

If I comment out the for/next loop and make x=0, this will populate JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][0] through JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][3] with the correct values in arrHotelsProdCols(0,0) through arrHotelsProdCols(3,0). I check this using an alert function onDblClick after opening the .asp page.

I can also see the text written to the ‘page source’:

```
JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][0] = '4 MEX HOTEL & LIVING';
JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][1] = '3 STAR';
JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][2] = '2KM';
JSarrHotelsProdCols[0][3] = '8KM';
```

However, when I run the for/next loop I cannot see the values in the JSarrHotelsProdCols array using the same alert function, but I can see all 612 x 4 statements written out correctly in the ‘page source’.

Why is this not working when I loop through this assignment but it works when I don’t loop through it?

Let me know if you need more info, I wasn't sure how much is enough.

Thanks.

Comment: ecarrizo, anyone, the [x][0] column text sometimes contains an apostrophe as in, St. Paul's. So as I loop through the 612 rows I hit one of these cases and boom. Is there a way deal with an apostrophe or should I not allow them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line inside the loop is missing an apostrophe. Change...

```
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][0] =  "&arrHotelsProdCols(0,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
```

...to...

```
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][0] =  '"&arrHotelsProdCols(0,x)&"';" & vbCrLf
```

You can escape apostrophes in JavaScript that may be inside your array values with a backslash, eg `Replace(arrHotelsProdCols(0,x), "'", "\'")`. Alternately you could replace the single quotes with double quotes (if double quotes won't exist in your array values), eg...

```
response.write  "JSarrHotelsProdCols["&x&"][0] =  """&arrHotelsProdCols(0,x)&""";" & vbCrLf
```

(note that the double quotes are duplicated as VBScript requires this if they are already inside a VBScript string)

Comment: Thanks John. The missing apostrophe above was lost upon posting to this forum. Replacing the apostrophe with double quotes worked on the data I have. Is the Replace you mentioned a Javascript replace? I am moving values from a vbarray (arrHotelsProdCols) to a javascript array (JSarrHotelsProdCols), that Replace won't work if the array cannot be populated first?

Comment: arrHotelsProdCols(0,x) = Replace(arrHotelsProdCols(0,x), "'", "`")

Comment: The `Replace` is VBScript and will do the replacement on the server-side, not in your resulting client-side JavaScript.